# ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I'm running this simple flask app in vs code. Dockerized it and loaded to ECS. The task is exiting with the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/**init**.py)

The base image I'm using is python3.10.

Following is the dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 6):

Trying the following in python 3.9:

```py
>>> from collections import MutableMapping
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

So I'm guessing your problem is you're using python 3.10 where you need to do:

```py
>>> from collections.abc import MutableMapping
```

Comment: in this app, i'm not explicitly importing this module...following is the code:                                          from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

# list of cat images
images = [
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/docker-curriculum.appspot.com/o/catnip%2F0.gif?alt=media&token=0fff4b31-b3d8-44fb-be39-723f040e57fb",
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/docker-curriculum.appspot.com/o/catnip%2F1.gif?alt=media&token=2328c855-572f-4a10-af8c-23a6e1db574c",

Comment: how do I make the interpreter look for collections.abc rather than collections?

Comment: @user13121562 this probably means `Flask` or something else is importing `MutableMapping` in this wrong way - consider trying to use an earlier (`<=3.9`) version of python3.

Comment: @ssp..its working with 3.9! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

if you update the flask package to `>=2.0` it will import it correctly also in python `3.10`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're doing the same [docker tutorial](https://docker-curriculum.com/) that I am.

@geza.denes is right, we need flask 2.0 or greater.

you can update this in flask-app/requirements.txt

Rebuild your docker image and run it again, should work!

Answer (score 0):

For **Python 3.10.6**

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/init.py)

For me Modules Mapping, MutableMapping and Sequence were missing in the **/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/init.py** adding them solved the problem.

```
from _collections_abc import Mapping
from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
from _collections_abc import Sequence
```